# Java: package java.time does not exist using Intellij

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, intellij-idea, time, java-11

I have creted a maven project for my selenium project in Intellij IDEA Community Version 2022.3.1 and using JDK11. Now while running testng.xml file I get an error `java: package java.time does not exist`.

In Project Settings->Modules->Sources-> Language Level, i used the values 8 and 11 but still getting the same error.

I am expected that while executing the testng.xml file,my tests should run without any error.

In my baseClass I am using `driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(Duration.ofSeconds(10));`
and also imported the package `import java.time.Duration`

What can cause this?

Comment: maybe here's your issue: https://www.jeffryhouser.com/index.cfm/2018/2/1/Why-cant-IntelliJ-find-javatime-with-JDK-9

Comment: Thanks a lot @stulukse, It worked as you indicated. But when I reload the page the value is set 1.7 again. Is there any way to avoid this.?

Comment: did you set java level in pom.xml? <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

Comment: @siggemannen I have set the values as follows :                                                <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
    <maven.compiler.source>${java.version}</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>${java.version}</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

Comment: Does it help if you click on `Reload All Maven Projects` in Maven tool window? (https://prnt.sc/6ldHDBoc9OU7)

Comment: @EgorKlepikov I tried this option too, but the value changes back to 1.7

Comment: To All, In my pom.xml file I changed the value of the following to 11 in the build section and it worked fine.                                                                                        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.8.0</version>
          <configuration>
            <source>11</source>
            <target>11</target>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>

Answer (score 1):

With the help of the community, the solution to this problem is:

1. File->Project Settings->Modules->Sources-> Language Level set the value to 11
2. File-> Settings->Build, Execution, Deployment->Compiler->Java Compiler set the "Target bytecode version" to 11
3. If you are using pom.xml file and have a build then set the following:

   ```
   <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId> 
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId> 
          <version>3.8.0</version> 
          <configuration> 
                    <source>11</source> 
                    <target>11</target>
         </configuration>
   </plugin>
   ```